# How to combine many(1000) png file together in one big file system where we can iterate and get all if needed

Tags: java, hadoop

I am putting many images on HDFS. However each one is taking 64MB Block there.As the count of images are very high So wanted to put all image information in one big file. Now this will be feed  to mapper to process it faster . What inputformat i can use? Or do i need to use sequencefile concepts ?i am not much sure as how to proceed further could someone please suggest some better way to deal this.

Comment: you want them in a database?

Comment: No. those are intermediate input to my Map task on hadoop. More i am concerned as i need to save DataNode memory i.e. if image is of 3kb then it takes 64MB(default) for hdfs block size

Comment: Take a look at SequenceFiles, which are specifically address the "small files problem"

Comment: Thanks it seems sequence file is good option. i should try my hand thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just throw them all in a Zip.

Really you would be better off using a Database (for example MongoDB) and store them all in there though.